# I inquire about how to use NPM download continuously without setting environment variables in Windows 11

Tags: node.js, npm

After decompressing Node.js into a .zip file, I am trying to use it without setting an environment variable, but I have some problems.

The unzipped directory address is `C:\study\node.js` . The directory location where node.exe exists will be `C:\study\node.js\node-v16.15.0-win-x64`.

However, after unpacking, in the folder where node.exe exists, run it with CMD administrator privileges, and both `npm -v` and `node -v` can check the version normally.

However, after executing `npm install {packageName}` , when I run npm commands again, an error occurs saying `node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936` .

After deleting the Node.js files and unpacking them again, I observed that the `C:\study\node.js\node-v16.15.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm` folder disappeared after installation. Is there any way to continue to download npm libraries?

I would like to download and use npm libraries by setting the assumption that environment variables cannot be set.

Since I rarely use Node.js, I don't even need Node.js to work properly.

If there is no way other than setting environment variables, I am curious because I have never used Node.js before. Why does npm delete npm and subdirectories inside npm_module folder after install?